# SVG object inside Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I tried to put a SVG object inside a flexbox and it ended messing up the whole thing:

https://jsfiddle.net/h8n1wxcn/

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
   
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
   
.child {
    flex-grow: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}
   
.svg {
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class="svg">
        <object id="loader" type="image/svg+xml" data="https://la-cascade.io/content/images/2015/06/kiwi.svg" width="150px">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <p>Yo</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like the .svg div to be centered, when I replace the object tag by some random text, it works perfectly, but suddenly when I put the object tag instead, it ends up removing or hiding the last div of my flexbox

Comment: You need closing tag `</object>`

Comment: omg, that's so dumb ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You have to close `object` tag.

Also you can use `img` instead of `object`.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
   
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
   
.child {
    flex-grow: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}
   
.svg {
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class="svg">
        <img src="https://la-cascade.io/content/images/2015/06/kiwi.svg" width="150"/>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <p>Yo</p>
    </div>
</div>
```